# Get info shown in user.aspx using powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, permissions

I'm looking for a way to get a list of all my site users with powershell. I'd like to get the info shown in user.aspx and then query the SharePoint groups and AD group recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "<http://your site>"
if ($web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{
    write-host "this has unique permissions"
    foreach($roleAssignment in $web.RoleAssignments)
    {            
        $isLimited = $true
        foreach($roleDefinition in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
        {
            if($roleDefinition.Name -ne 'Limited Access')
            {
                $isLimited =$false
            }
        }
        if($isLimited -ne $true)
        {
            write-host -foregroundcolor green "Name: "$roleAssignment.Member.Name
            foreach($roleDefinition in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
            {
                if($roleDefinition.Name -ne 'Limited Access')
                {                     
                    write-host -foregroundcolor red "Permission Name: "$roleDefinition.Name "..."
                }
            }
        }
    }      
}
```